# PHPMailer "Relaying denied. Proper authentification required"

Tags: php, email, web, smtp, phpmailer

I have an issue with PHPMailer. I want to send an e-mail form myself to myself, when a certain form is filled on my website (with the informations of the form in it),  but I can't get it to work. PHP doesn't send any error (I made sure it's enabled), but with SMTPDebug, I get this:

```
2015-02-12 07:35:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2015-02-12 07:35:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:
2015-02-12 07:35:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:
2015-02-12 07:35:58 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550 5.7.1 ... Relaying denied. Proper authentication required.
2015-02-12 07:35:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-02-12 07:35:58 SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: me@mydomain.com
```

Here's the code sample:

```
        require("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
        $mail = new phpmailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->Host      = "smtp.server.com"; //Mod

        $mail->From      = "me@mydomain.com"; //Mod
        $mail->FromName  = "Automatic e-mail, no reply";
        $mail->AddAddress("me@mydomain.com"); //Mod

        $mail->Subject   = "A student forgot his password";
        $mail->Body      = $class.'\r\n'.$fname.' '.$lname;
        $mail->WordWrap  = 70;

        if(!$mail->Send())
            $sent = false;
        else
            $sent = true;
```

(The `//Mod` at the end of a line indicates that I modified the data for privacy reasons.)

Now I've read some people fixed this by commenting this line:

```
mail->IsSMTP();
```

But I only get another error when I do that:

> Could not instantiate mail function

Which seems quite logical to me.

Comment: "Could not instantiate mail function" means that your php is not configured to allow the `mail()` function, or you have no local mail server.

Comment: Troubleshooting things like this is covered in [the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server requires a valid authenticated user, you need to add authorization credentials. Of course change the values of Username and Password for valid authorization credentials in your SMTP server.

```
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "yourauthorizeduser"; // It could be your@authorized.user"
$mail->Password = "v3rys3cr3t";
```